# qt - view geomview (.off ) file

Tags: 3d, c++

I want to open a .off file and view the content 3d model using libQGLViewer, qt-creator.

I don't know how to display the 3d model after opening its .off file.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open .off model"), "/home", tr("*.off"));
```

Comment: `tr("*.off")` - I'm pretty sure you don't want to translate the file extension to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick gander through the examples it looks like QGLViewer is a thin wrapper around a opengl window using the legacy api.

So what you really need is a way to load a .off file to render in legacy opengl. [it looks like a very simple format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)), even simpler than .obj. So simple that IMO it is worth it for you to figure out on your own.